# Immutable deployments and updates and sustain environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just created a new Elastic Beanstalk application and I set it up with the options below.[image]

Where the Deployment and Updates are set to `Immutable`.

What I didn't realize was that this was going to reset all of the environment variables set in the dashboard for that app.

I'm curious how your supposed to have environment variables and use this `Immutable` setting? Is this even the culprit for why my variables aren't saving?

Comment: This is a very valid question, and a worksround would still be very desirable. Anything new on this front?